# Deprecating a Nested Type in Favor of a Different Nested Type

Tags: swift

I have a nested type nested in a structure I want to remove from my project, but I want to keep the nested type, nested elsewhere. This is a close approximation of what my code looks like:

```swift
struct OldType {
    @available(*, deprecated, renamed: "NewType.MyNestedType")
    typealias MyNestedType = UInt8
}

struct NewType {
    typealias MyNestedType = UInt8
}
```

The problem is that in existing instances of using `OldType.MyNestedType`, the fixit tries replacing only the trailing dot syntax, not the whole type, which results in `OldType.NewType.MyNestedType`, which is obviously wrong.

Is there a way to redirect the whole Typed path and not just the last component?

Comment: While I find this humorous, I was able to resolve my solution by deprecating OldType itself, which then allows for the fixme to automatically correct it. However, I want the question to remain open because my situation is just lucky. I still see potential situations where the answer would be helpful.